# R Shiny Error C stack usage is too close to the limit

Tags: shiny

I am having this error when I deploy my Shiny app to the web, which works **all right at my own computer.**

Error: C stack usage  7980980 is too close to the limit

The data set is less than 2Mb, although there are some loops which would cost a few seconds to run. Is this related to the free account version?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you just have a simple coding mistake that is causing this. It doesn't have to do with the free account version.

I had this same error in Shiny and the problem was that I was performing a merge that exploded the size of one of the datasets.

I would suggest using breakpoints and stepping through your code line by line to find out what line is breaking your code.